# How to use sed on macOS to replace a line with bash script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I am on macOS High Sierra, and I've had a few issues with sed,
after spending a day on Google and this site, I've honestly tried everything I could think of and was suggested.

I have an example.txt file with 3 lines.
line1
line2
line3

The 3 lines can be anything, I do not know them upfront. (scenario)
And at some point I do know what the line is going to be.

All I wish to achieve is to use 'whatever' onliner that basically says:
in that file, replace line 2, with the new data.

`sed -i "2s/.*/$NEW_DATA/" "$FILENAME"`

This should work, but on macOS, this does not.

`sed -ie "2s/.*/$NEW_DATA/" "$FILENAME"`

Note the e? Someone on here suggested to add an e, and yes, that works.. but it means it adds the e behind the .txt. I end up with 2 files, example.txt and example.txte

`sed -i'' "2s/.*/$NEW_DATA/" "$FILENAME"`

Note the '' behind -i, and yes, without a space? This should work too.
It doesn't, it will complain that command c requires \

I could go on, but the request is quite simple:

on macOS, in a bash shell script, how do I simply replace a specified line of text in a .txt file, with a completely new line of text -- not knowing what the line of text was before?

If this can be a simple macOS one liner with awk or whatever, that's fine. It doesn't have to be sed. But when I search this site, it seems to be the recommended one to go with in this regards.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you use -i'' -e ? I always thought the -e is implicit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From the [sed man](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) page in macOS:

```
-i extension
         Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension. 
         If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.
```

Therefore this can be used to replace line 2 without keeping backup:

```
sed -i '' "2s/.*/$NEW_DATA/" testfile.txt
```

If the goal is just to replace contents of line 2 `awk` could also be used, for example:

```
awk 'NR==2{$0="your content"}1' testfile.txt > testfile.tmp && mv testfile.tmp testfile.txt
```

Comment: Just -i will not work on macOS, I already mentioned this. I tried -i'' and -i ''

Comment: Unless `sed` was modified in macOS high sierra this should be working, in any case at least the `awk` alternative works? Could you paste the errors

Comment: @user8964123 The key here is that there *must* be a space between `-I` and `''`, or it won't work. Unfortunately, GNU sed doesn't allow it with a space there, so there's no way to do this portably.